# How can I create a mesh of closed shape?

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, mesh, polygons

I have this hexagon that defined according to these points

```
Boundrs = {{-(π/3), -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {-((2  π)/3), 
    0}, {-(π/3), π/Sqrt[3]}, {π/3, π/
     Sqrt[3]}, {(2  π)/3, 
    0}, {π/3, -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {π/
     3, -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {-(π/3), -(π/Sqrt[3])}};
```

I would like to get a regular mesh of points `{xi,yi}` that are only inside or at the border.
I tried this

```
region = Polygon[Boundrs];
points = RandomPoint[region, 900];
Show[ListLinePlot[Boundrs, PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> 1], 
 ListPlot[points, ImageSize -> 200]]
```

[image]

but it gives a random mesh, I would like to get regular mesh, something like this

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pts[n_ : 30] := Select[RegionMember[Polygon @ Boundrs]][
   Join @@ CoordinateBoundsArray[CoordinateBounds@Boundrs, Into[n]]];


Graphics[{FaceForm[Opacity[.7, LightOrange]], EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], 
  Polygon @ Boundrs, Black, PointSize[Medium], Point @ pts[]}]
```

[image]

Replace `pts[]` with `pts[10]` to get

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With your polygon being:

```
regP = Polygon[Boundrs]
```

Generate a grid of points according to:

```
{Max@#, Min@#} &@Boundrs

{(2 \[Pi])/3, -((2 \[Pi])/3)}

pts = Flatten[#, 1] &@
   Table[{x, y}, {x, -2 \[Pi]/3, 
     2 \[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/15}, {y, -2 \[Pi]/3, 2 \[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/15}];
```

Find points in region:

```
ptsinreg = Pick[pts, (RegionMember[regP, #] & /@ pts)];


Graphics[{
  Red, FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], regP
  , Blue, Point@ptsinreg
  }
 , Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT-1** Points on an angle

Define a line with a 30 degree slope

```
f[x_, c_] := Tan[\[Pi]/6] x + c
```

Generate points with different y-intercepts to cover the range.

```
pt00 = Flatten[#, 1] &@
   Table[{x, f[x, c]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.2}, {c, -3, 3, 0.2}];
```

same drill:

```
ptsinreg = Pick[pt00, (RegionMember[regP, #] & /@ pt00)];
Graphics[{
  Red, FaceForm[Nest[Lighter, Yellow, 3]], EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], regP
  , Blue, Point@ptsinreg
  }
 , Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT-2**

To get points on the boundary (choose resolution):

```
dreg = DiscretizeRegion[regP, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.05]
```

[image]

```
pts01 = MeshCoordinates[dreg];
```

No need to do `RegionMember` this time.

```
Graphics[{
  Red, FaceForm[Nest[Lighter, Yellow, 3]], EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], regP
  , Blue, Point@pts01
  }
 , Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: why there are not point on the borderline?

Comment: That's a decision for `RegionMember` to make. I do see some, but cannot force them (or at least I don't know of a method to force the function to do it). Can you specifically say which point is missing?

Comment: @valarmorghulis I have added another strategy.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

To ensure that the boundary contain points,we can calculate the height of such polygon (which equal to `h=π/Sqrt[3]`) and divide it into `n` parts.

```
Boundrs = {{-(π/3), -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {-((2 π)/3), 
    0}, {-(π/3), π/Sqrt[3]}, {π/3, π/
     Sqrt[3]}, {(2 π)/3, 
    0}, {π/3, -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {π/
     3, -(π/Sqrt[3])}, {-(π/3), -(π/Sqrt[3])}};
region = Polygon[Boundrs];

h = RegionBounds[region][[2, 2]];
θ = π/6;
e1 = AngleVector[θ];
e2 = AngleVector[π - θ];
n = 8;
c = (1/n) h/Norm[e1 + e2];
pts = c*{x, y} . {e1, e2} /. 
   Solve[(c*{x, y} . {e1, e2}) ∈ region, {x, y}, Integers];
pts2 = Join[pts, Boundrs];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> pts2];
MeshRegion[mesh, 
 MeshCellHighlight -> {{1, All} -> Yellow, {0, All} -> Black}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
g = Graphics[Polygon[Boundrs], ImageSize -> 50];
pos = PixelValuePositions[ColorNegate[Binarize[g]], 1];
tran = RescalingTransform[CoordinateBounds[pos], 
   CoordinateBounds[Boundrs]];
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Blue], Polygon[Boundrs], Red, 
  Point[tran@pos]}]
```

[image]